# ngIf is not triggered when value changes

Tags: angular, ngonchanges, angular-changedetection

I have a simple mat-spinner which should be triggered when `isLoading` is `true`. The variable changes as intended, but the mat-spinner is not visible. It is only visible if I change `isLoading` to always be `true`.

Am I missing something? 
Thanks in advance!

app.component.ts:

```
import { Component, OnDestroy } from '@angular/core';
import { UtilityService } from './services/utility.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss']
})
export class AppComponent implements OnDestroy {
  title = 'cpt';

  isLoading = true;
  subscription;

  constructor(private utilityService: UtilityService) {
    this.subscription = this.utilityService.getIsLoadingObservable().subscribe(isLoading => {
      this.isLoading = isLoading;
    });
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    this.subscription.unsubscribe();
  }
}
```

app.component.html:

```
<div class="loading-shade" *ngIf="isLoading">
  <mat-spinner></mat-spinner>
</div>
<app-router></app-router>
```

utility.service.ts:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { BehaviorSubject, Observable } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class UtilityService {

  public isLoading: BehaviorSubject<boolean> = new BehaviorSubject(false);

  constructor() { }

  getIsLoadingObservable(): Observable<boolean> {
    return this.isLoading.asObservable();
  }

  async setIsLoading(val: boolean) {
    await this.isLoading.next(val);
  }
}
```

EDIT Adding component which triggers the setter function:
start.component.ts:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NodeService } from '../../services/node.service';
import { UtilityService } from '../../services/utility.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-start',
  templateUrl: './start.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./start.component.scss']
})
export class StartComponent {

  isLoading = false;

  constructor(
    private nodeService: NodeService,
    private utilityService: UtilityService) {}

    async selectNode(val: string) {
      await this.utilityService.setIsLoading(true);
      if (val === 'bank') {
        await this.nodeService.setNode('http://localhost:8091');
      } else if (val === 'auditor') {
        await this.nodeService.setNode('http://localhost:8092');
      } else if (val === 'spv') {
        await this.nodeService.setNode('http://localhost:8093');
      } else {
        await this.nodeService.setNode('http://localhost:8094');
      }
      await this.utilityService.setIsLoading(false);
  }
}
```

Comment: who call `setIsLoading(false)`?

Comment: in your subscription just console.log(isLoading) to see what values are being emitted, also check type of value to make sure it is boolean

Comment: @JacopoSciampi another component calls it.

Comment: @danday74 did this and the value changes as intended but the spinner is not shown

Comment: can you provide a stack blitz? Because i did an example on my pc and works fine

Comment: @JacopoSciampi I will try to put it together!

Comment: Thakn you. Using setInterval is a bad bad pratcise. You should always avoid that, because you are not solving the problem. There is a reason that cause this problem, and needs to be resolved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay this has nothing to do with ngIf, sorry. The issue was the `setNode()` function, where the second `setIsLoading()` call (back to false) is directly made after the first, because the `await` is not working as expected.

Thanks all who tried to help!

Answer (score 0):

Your code is fine and works here as expected. You do have to manually run the `setIsLoading()` method, like this:

```
export class AppComponent implements OnDestroy {
    title = 'cpt';
    isLoading = true;
    subscription;
    test = false;

    constructor(private utilityService: UtilityService) {
      this.subscription = this.utilityService
        .getIsLoadingObservable()
        .subscribe(isLoading => {
          this.isLoading = isLoading;
        });

      setInterval(() => {
        this.test = !this.test;
        this.utilityService.setIsLoading(this.test);
      }, 2000);
    }

    ngOnDestroy() {
      this.subscription.unsubscribe();
    }
}
```

Comment: Maybe I should have added it from the beginning, I will edit the code above to add the component which calls the setIsLoading() function

Comment: also with your code within start.component everything is fine. do you actually call the 'selectNode()' function from somewhere?
everything working as expected here ...